# Converting a Joomla site to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I have a potential client who wants to take an existing Joomla site and translate it into Wordpress.  Is any sort of automagical conversion possible, or will I have to reconstruct the site in word press?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wordpress Codex gives some plugins that could help you importing from Joomla to Wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Joomla

Best practive however, depends on what you want to import: Users, articles, whole design, etc...

Comment: @AndrewWorthington Though I don't know how Joomla templating works, these two apps' APIs don't work in the same way so in this case you will need to use a new design/template, then import the articles in Wordpress. Some manual processing will be needed to get both versions to look alike but it's far from undoable.